# How should I handle large video datasets in Google Cloud ML Engine?

Tags: keras, google-cloud-storage, large-data, google-cloud-ml

I am experimenting with video classification using Keras in Cloud ML Engine. My dataset consists in video sequences saved as separate images (eg. seq1_frame1.png, seq1.frame2.png...) which I have uploaded to a GCS bucket.

I use a csv file referencing the start of end frames of different subclips, and a generator which feeds batch of clips to the model. The generator is responsible for loading frames from the bucket, reading them as images, and concatenating them as numpy arrays.

My training is fairly long, and I suspect the generator is my bottleneck due to the numerous reading operations.

In the exemples I found online, people usually save pre-formatted clips as tfrecords files directly to GCS. I feel like this solution isn't ideal for very large datasets as it implies duplicating the data, even more so if we decide to extract overlapping subclips.

Is there something wrong in my approach ? And more importantly, is there a "golden-standard" for using large video datasets for machine learning ?

PS : I explained my setup for reference, but my question is not bound to Keras, generators or Cloud ML.

Answer (score 1):

In this, you are almost always going to be trading time for space. You just have to work out which is more important.

In theory, for every frame, you have height*width*3 bytes. That's assuming 3 colour channels. One possible way you could save space is to use only one channel (probably choose green, or, better still, convert your complete dataset to greyscale). That would reduce your full size video data to one third size. Colour data in video tends to be at a lower resolution than luminance data so it might not affect your training, but it depends on your source files.

As you probably know, .png is a lossless image compression. Every time you load one, the generator will have to decompress first, and then concatenate to the clip. You could save even more space by using a different compression codec, but that would mean every clip would need full decompression and probably add to your time. You're right, the repeated decompression will take time. And saving the video uncompressed will take up quite a lot of space. There are places you could save space, though:

- reduce to greyscale (or green scale as above)
- temporally subsample frames (do you need EVERY consecutive frame, or could you sample every second one?)
- do you use whole frames or just patches? Can you crop or rescale the video sequences?
- are you using optical flow? It's pretty processor intensive, consider it as a pre-processing step, too, so you only have to do it once per clip (again this is trading space for time)